# Powershell Import-Csv then Get-Aduser results in all users in ad being displayed when a Blank Line appears

Tags: powershell, csv

I am writing a powershell script to disable users due to the fact that we get a list of them everyday and it is monotonous. I paste the list from the ticket into a csv formatted as Lastname, Firstname then run my script with imports the list, serches ad and ask if you want to disable if it finds them. Here is the code...

```
# Set variables
$Import = "C:\Scripts\Support Files\Users_To_Disable.csv"
$Export = "C:\Scripts\Support Files\Disabled_Users_Output.txt"

# Import user list
$Users = Import-CSV $Import

foreach ($User in $Users)

{

# Set user variables
$LastName = $User.("Surname")
$FirstName = $User.("GivenName")

# Use user variables from list to search ad
$UserName = (Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -like '$FirstName*' -and Surname -like '$LastName*'").SamAccountName

# What to do if it finds nothing
If ($UserName -eq $Null)

    {
    Write-Host $LastName, $FirstName NA -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Output "$LastName, $FirstName NA" | Out-File $Export -Append
    }   

# What to do if it finds a user
Else

    { 
    # Ask for user input
    Write-Host $LastName, $FirstName Found -ForegroundColor Green 
    Write-Host UserName = $UserName -ForegroundColor Green

    DO {

        $Disable = Read-Host "Do you want to disable user? (Y/N)"

        If($Disable -eq "Y")

            {
            # Disable the user
            Disable-ADAccount -Identity $UserName
            # Move the user
            Get-ADUser $UserName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Disabled - Retention,DC=intranet,DC=sw"
            # Add Disabled Users group
            Add-ADGroupMember "Disabled Users" -Members "$UserName"
            # Set Disable Users as primary group
            $Group = Get-ADGroup "Disabled Users" -Properties @("PrimaryGroupToken")
            Get-ADUser "$UserName" | Set-ADUser -Replace @{PrimaryGroupID=$Group.PrimaryGroupToken}
            # Remove all other groups
            $User = Get-ADUser "$UserName" -Properties MemberOf
            $Groups = $User.MemberOf |ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroup $_ } 
            $Groups | ForEach-Object { Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $User -Confirm:$false }
            # Output 
            Write-Host $LastName, $FirstName Disabled -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Output "$LastName, $FirstName Disabled" | Out-File $Export -Append
            Break
            }

        }

    Until ($Disable -eq "N")
    }

}

Invoke-Item $Export
```

All of that works, what is scary is that if there are blank cells above a user then it returns all of the users in ad and asks if you want to disable all of them. In other words if the csv looks like this...

```
Surname GivenName
User    Test
```

Everything works fine, but if it looks like this...

```
Surname GivenName

User    Test
```

Pandemonium, well not really but it does ask if you want to initiate a resume generating event, which I don't so how can I build in some safety that would stop it from returning all of ad when there are blanks in the csv before users?

Comment: `if(-not($FirstName) -and -not($LastName)){ continue }` before the call the `Get-ADUser`

Comment: Add the `if` statement right before that, yes (or filter out empty columns like @MikeGaruccio suggests)

Comment: Are you suggesting that I add this on line 22 or at the $UserName = (Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -like '$FirstName*' -and Surname -like '$LastName*'").SamAccountName

Comment: Just before that last line you mention

Comment: Mike's suggestion worked I just wonder what happens if there isn't a Surname but there is a Givenname

Comment: It shouldn't happen but I'm trying to fool proof this since I won't be the only one using it once I'm done creating it

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm as well, for the record.

Comment: if you want to check for both then you could always add a `-and` to the `Where-Object` and check for both GivenName and Surname and only proceed if both are there, but then you'd have the chance that a user that was supposed to be deleted doesn't actually get removed (whether this is an issue or not depends on your environment and compliance requirements)

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the blank lines by filtering out Null values on your import, which should resolve the problem.

`$Users = Import-CSV $Import | Where-Object {$_.Surname}`

Comment: That did it, I figured it was simple. Thank You.